# Generate degree-bound LFSR to approximate given sequence

Tags: algorithms, approximation, shift-register

Given an output sequence, $S$, we can use the Berlekamp-Massey algorithm to find the shortest LFSR, of order $n \leq |S|$, which exactly generates that sequence. Is it possible to efficiently compute an LFSR, in $GF(2)$, of order $n \leq n_0 < |S|$, which best approximates $S$? Best approximation means with the fewest possible errors, and by errors we consider the element-wise discrepancies (i.e. no insertions/deletions are allowed).

I searched for similar papers and the only relevant one I could find was [Modified Berlekamp-Massey algorithm for approximating the k-error linear complexity of binary sequences](https://repository.lboro.ac.uk/articles/online_resource/Modified_Berlekamp-Massey_algorithm_for_approximating_the_k-error_linear_complexity_of_binary_sequences/9405239). However, it is an exponential algorithm (and I don't quite understand it).

Comment: I wonder if the approximate problem is related to Learning Parity with Noise.

Comment: @D.W. I think it is $n <= |S|$. When the polynomial given by B-M has a degree $<= |S|/2$, it is unique. Take a look here https://www.embeddedrelated.com/showarticle/1099.php

Answer (score 2):

The measure you are interested in is usually called $k-$error linear complexity. See [this review](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-24582-7_1) in Asiacrypt 2003 by Niederreiter. There are unpaywalled versions of this paper around. The cryptanalytic goal (first described in the book *Stability Theory of Stream Ciphers* by Ding et. al.) is to determine (given some fixed $k>0$) the *shortest* LFSR generating a sequence of length $N.$

There are various algorithms for computing it under various assumptions. For example if the sequence is assumed to have period $p^n$ and is over $GF(p)$ faster algorithms are possible. Keywords to look for include the Games-Chan algorithm (complexity $O(n)$ for sequence length $2^n$), Stamp and Martin algorithm (modification of Games-Chan). Look at Meidl's work [here](https://research.sabanciuniv.edu/44/1/3011800000282.pdf)aand elsewhere as well.

You can simply search the papers citing Niederreiter's review paper and find out more.

**Edit:** The OP has clarified the problem which I had slightly misunderstood. Indeed the paper by Lauder and Paterson is the way to go in this case.

Comment: I was aware of the measure, but it does not generate the LFSR itself, which is what I ultimately want. I found the paper "Computing the Error Linear Complexity Spectrum of a Binary Sequence of Period $2^n$" by Lauder and Paterson, which is quite close to what I want. The idea was to find the first $k$ in the spectrum for which the complexity is below $n_0$, then compute the error sequence $e$ (as described in the paper) to achieve that complexity and, finally, use Berlekamp-Massey's algorithm on the sequence $S \oplus e$ to get the desired LFSR.

Comment: Of course, Lauder-Paterson require sequences with a period of length $2^n$, which is restrictive. My solution to this is to append as many $0$s as necessary to complete a power of 2, and assign these bits a cost of 0. The only problem with this approach is that the Lauder-Paterson algorithm gives the complexity of the sequence $s^\infty$, where $s$ is a single period-sequence, whereas Berlekamp-Massey generates the LFSR for the given sequence with the aim of producing it only once. Is there any modification/correction I can make to overcome this discrepancy?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, one cannot overcome this discrepancy in any meaningful fashion